# Storm HiveBolt missing records due to batching of Hive transactions

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-kafka, apache-storm

To store the processed records I am using HiveBolt in Storm topology with following arguments.

```
- id: "MyHiveOptions"
    className: "org.apache.storm.hive.common.HiveOptions" 
      - "${metastore.uri}"                       # metaStoreURI
      - "${hive.database}"                       # databaseName
      - "${hive.table}"                          # tableName   
    configMethods:
          - name: "withTxnsPerBatch"
            args:
              - 2
          - name: "withBatchSize"
            args:
              - 100
          - name: "withIdleTimeout"
            args:
              - 2      #default value 0
          - name: "withMaxOpenConnections"
            args:
              - 200     #default value 500
          - name: "withCallTimeout"
            args:
              - 30000     #default value 10000
          - name: "withHeartBeatInterval"
            args:
              - 240     #default value 240
```

There are missing transaction in Hive due to batch no being completed and records are flushed. (For example: 1330 records are processed but only 1200 records are in hive. 130 records missing.)

How can I overcome this situation? How can I fill the batch so that the transaction is triggered and the records are stored in hive.

```
Topology : Kafka-Spout --> DataProcessingBolt
           DataProcessingBolt -->HiveBolt (Sink)
           DataProcessingBolt -->JdbcBolt (Sink)
```

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that batch was not completed and the records were thrown away?

Comment: When I checked the count in hive table there was a difference. In parallel I have also setup mysqlbolt to check consistency. I tried to test with smaller batch same TxnsPerBatch=2 and BatchSize=10 but no luck.

Comment: Storm is a run-at-least-once platform (unless using Trident). So there's a real possibility that Storm ran some tuples multiple times. To determine if that is the case then we know how many records were put into Storm from whatever source you are using.

Comment: I completely understand - Storm's run-at-least-once platform. As a test, I am trying to process just one message and expect one record in Hive table. Unfortunately I don't see that record in Hive table, whereas I can see the same record inserted in Mysql table. In Storm UI - I see the HiveBolt acknowledging the message.

Comment: I have updated question with Storm Topology

Comment: So the HiveBolt acknowledges the tuple, but doesn't write the message to Hive? Even though you have batch size configured to 100, at some point the HiveBolt should clear out its buffer and write. This suggests a bug of some sort with the HiveBolt.

Comment: Take a look at what youe topology/bolts are doing  - at least with Trident, ususally when we cannot write to Hive, we end up with the remaining tuples not getting acked, and looping until eventually they can be processed. On the other hand, the idleTimeOut property (of the HiveBolt) should make HiveWriter commit their data - make sure this is smaller than your message timeout.